# Physical location of library template

Tags: 2010, document-library, list-template

I have a Document Library template that I need to move from my Dev environment to my Prod environment.

I looked all over the 14 hive and in the site in SP Designer for this file, but could not find it.

Where would I find this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the document library was saved as a template, then it would be in the list template gallery in site settings.  From there, it can be downloaded to your desktop, uploaded to a production list template gallery, and new document libraries provisioned from it.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the template? Normally they're installed with Features. So find your Feature folder in the TEMPLATE\FEATURES folder, then you should be able to find your template (the schema.xml file).